# Reset Build Order of a VS2012 Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build

I have a VS2012 solution with consists of more than 30 projects.

I ordered them manually for the build process by setting dependencies in the build order as desired.

Is there an easy way to revert those changes from within Visual Studio? 
(without editing the settings for all those 30 projects again.)

Note: Reverting form source code management, which would be the most obvious option, is not the desired solution here.

Comment: No.  It takes a couple of seconds to reset the dependencies for a project.  That should add up to a minute of your life, not competitive with waiting 2 hours for an answer ;)

Comment: you know it would probably take me about 5-10 minutes to undo the changes. since the GUI to do those changes is really not user friendly when you have to select each item in the dropdown, and then scroll through the list of projects and unmark checkboxes. And it would definitely take me some time to think about how the references were at the beginning, and I had to reapply them.

Comment: 1. I not have to do this right now, so waiting is no problem ;) 2. Making all the correct assignments manually, that are actually based on project references would really take some time.

Comment: Thank you, that would be the best option if someone didn't do the changes already, and no scm was used.